# Round up last two numbers after comma javascript

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

I am searching for the solution to round this number '19,48' up to '19,50' with
javascript. I found some functions as Math/round etc. but they don't round up the 48 to 50.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the "," in those numbers a decimal point? If so, just round to one decimal place, and if you need to *display* it as "19,50" you'll need to concatenate a `"0"` on the end. If it's *not* a decimal place what is it? Also, would you round down for 19.42?

Comment: ***sigh*** Another ask-and-run. @ Freshtea: When asking for help, *stick around* for a few minutes to answer questions like nnnnnn's above.

Answer (score 4):

If your number is a javascript `Number`, then you can multiply it by 10 and then divide it:

```
var num = 19.48;
var result = Math.round(num * 10) / 10; // 19.5
```

Comment: use `parseFloat(numword.replace(',','.'))` to get the number.

Comment: only if `num` is not a number

Answer (score -1):

you have to use the `toFixed()` method.

```
var num=19.48;
    num.toFixed(1);
```

Comment: forget to use 1 as parameter because we need only one decimal